# Hyperlink in an ASP Gridview with a CommandName

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know how to add a commandName to an asp hyperlink in a gridview.
Or is there any other way of doing this. I know you can use a linkbutton but i need the user to be navigated to a new tab. The hyperlink can do this with the target attribute.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't have the best of both worlds built right in here (postback handing, allowing for `CommandName` *and* `Target`); you will need to A) use a link and disregard commands, or B) use a `LinkButton` to handle the command in the postback then redirect manually.

In the latter case B, you could perhaps register a script to execute the redirection and maintain specifying the target in that manner. For example:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    page,
    typeof(Page),
    "Redirect",
    "window.open(" + "\"" + url + "\"" + ", \"_blank\");",
    true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Hyperlink´s Properties it´s could be by the way:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="Lk1" runat="server" Target="_Blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("someid","detail?id={0}") %>'><asp:Label ID="Label1" Runat="Server" /></asp:HyperLink>
```